# how should i make my database fetch continously

Tags: database, mongodb, discord, discord.js, bots

```
function shield() {
  setInterval(async function () {
    const ProfileModelS = require("../models/ProfileSchema");
    await ProfileModelS.find({}).then((doc) => {
      doc.forEach(async (u) => {
        if (u.ShieldPoints <= 0) return console.log(u.Name);
        if (u.ShieldPoints > 0) {
          await ProfileModelS.findOneAndUpdate(
            { userID: u.userID },
            {
              $inc: {
                ShieldPoints: -1,
              },
            },
            console.log("done")
          );
        }
      });
    });
  }, 1000);
}

module.exports = shield
```

I want my mongodb to fetch the model on every Interval but its not doing that, whenever i run my code it fetches the model for example, it will fetch
[{name: 'Joseph' , Points: 10}, {name: 'carman' , Points: -1}, {name: 'thee' , Points: 2}]
according to code it will properly not reduce the points of objects whose points are less than 0,
but it will go on decreasing points of object more than 0, i want it to stop reducing points if the objects point reaches 0, and it should go on decreasing the points of object whose points are greater than 0

In short the process for a particular object should be stop once it points reaches 0

Comment: change second if to else and try

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Promise.all` to iterate over all of the retrieved models, as you seem to want to perform an `async` operation on every instance with `ShieldPoints > 0` and your `findOneAndUpdate` operations are independent of one another.

```js
function shield() {
  // Import the model schema
  const ProfileModelS = require("../models/ProfileSchema");

  setInterval(async function () {
    // Retrieve all models
    const users = await ProfileModelS.find();
    
    // Parallelise the process of updating the models that need to be updated
    Promise.all(
      users.map(async (user) => {
        if (user.ShieldPoints > 0) {
          await ProfileModelS.findOneAndUpdate(
            { userID: user.userID },
            {
              $inc: {
                ShieldPoints: -1,
              },
            },
          );
        };
      })
    );
  }, 1000);
}

module.exports = shield
```

However, if your `findOneAndUpdate` operations do not complete within the `1000ms` interval, then the code will issue a second `findOneAndUpdate` operation for those same model instances. This could then cause your models to update more than once, which is unintended behaviour. To address this, you would need to add some form of guard against this.

Comment: thank you for your concern but your code is lagging my whole system, and i think now i should make a different base project to handle this project , i mean like a secret web or smh